# SD card suddenly turned to read only

Tags: format, sd-card

I have a old strontium SD card which i am using from many days but suddenly i found that i cant write any file to it anymore. Whenever i put a file in it it shows "You cant write files to read only memory". I think there may be virus so i tried to format but it shows "Windows was an able to complete the format" and in mobile the format option was locked to be clicked.And i am able to explore the files in it.

Now please tell what to do. Do not suggest me to buy a new SD card. If the data lost let it lost but how to recover it.

Comment: 1. This question isn't programming related and should probably be posted at Super User or some other StackExchange.  2. Some SD cards have a switch on the edge for read-only.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Shall i delete this question from here ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using a micro SD card with an adapter.
Usually adapters have a switch to lock/unlock writing to the SD card. And are pretty hidden.

Anyway, there are more appropriate places for this type of question.